# Package 'mercurial' has no installation candidate, how do I fix it?

Tags: package-management, mercurial

E: Package 'mercurial' has no installation candidate. How can i solve this problem?

> ```
> sudo apt-get install mercurial
> ```
>
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Package mercurial is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, oris only available from another source

Comment: If possible, please update the question with the content of your /etc/apt/sources.list file. A wild guess might be that you don't have the universe component active.

Comment: What is your version of ubuntu? Also, `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` (as the @andol say) then copy/paste that.

Comment: @ZDroid `gksu gedit` (or `gksudo gedit`, or, on Kubuntu, `kdesudo gedit`) [is preferable because it doesn't create configuration problems for the graphical application being run](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).

Comment: Yes Kagan, sorry for my inattention. ;)

Answer (score 4):

As [andol suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115884/package-mercurial-has-no-installation-candidate-how-do-i-fix-it#comment137070_115884), this is likely a result of [the Universe repository component](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#What_are_Repositories.3F) being disabled. [Searching the Ubuntu package database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) for `mercurial` reveals [it's in Universe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/mercurial).

One way to enable the Universe repository is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `software-properties-gtk`. In the *Ubuntu Software* tab, under *Downloadable from the Internet*, make sure the checkbox for *Community-maintained Open Source software (universe)* is checked. For more information on enabling Universe, see:

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Then, to install Mercurial, run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

[mercurial [image: Install mercurial]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mercurial) can also be installed from the Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this by enabling the “Universe” repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```